# Why ESP32 with static IP address can't connect to internet but can ping normally?

Tags: httprequest, ping, esp32, android-wifi, static-ip-address

I have connected ESP32 to WIFI, but this WIFI must fix IP address, Gateway, Subnet mask, DNS and MAC. So, I assign them and test with two codes. The first one is with a [ping library](https://github.com/marian-craciunescu/ESP32Ping) and the 2nd one is with http request to Google.

Ping code

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESP32Ping.h>
 
const char* ssid = "test";
const char* password =  "test";
 
IPAddress staticIP(172, 16, 116, 90);
IPAddress gateway(172, 16, 116, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(172, 17, 10, 1);
    
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  if (WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet, dns, dns) == false) {
    Serial.println("Configuration failed.");
  }
    
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("Connecting...\n\n");
  }
 
  Serial.print("Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("Subnet Mask: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.subnetMask());
  Serial.print("Gateway IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print("DNS 1: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP(0));
  Serial.print("DNS 2: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP(1));
   
  bool success = Ping.ping("www.google.com", 3);
  
  if(!success){
    Serial.println("\nPing failed");
    return;
  }
  
  Serial.println("\nPing successful.");
}
    
void loop(){}
```

Http request code

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
  
const char* ssid = "test";
const char* password =  "test";

IPAddress staticIP(172, 16, 116, 90);
IPAddress gateway(172, 16, 116, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(172, 17, 10, 1);

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

if (WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet, dns, dns) == false) {
    Serial.println("Configuration failed.");
  }
  
  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
  
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("MAC address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  
}
  
void loop() {
  
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
  
    HTTPClient http;
  
    http.begin("www.google.com"); //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
  
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
  
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        
      }
  
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
  
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  } else {
    Serial.println("WiFi lost");
  }
  
  delay(10000);
  
}
```

After I tried, output of the first one is working normally. But the 2nd one seems like it can connect to Wi-Fi only one time but can't make request after that it lost connection. I so confused pls help.
It can't connect via mqtt too.

*Output 1st code*

[image: Output 1st code]

*Output 2nt code*

[image: Output 2nd code]

Answer (score -1):

change Dns Address.
IPAddress dns(172, 17, 10, 1); to
IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8);

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.